# How to spawn images forever? Sprite-Kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Im trying to create a dodgeball feature in my game and I need to repeatedly spawn a dodgeball and the current code I used (shown below) results in *Thread 1: Exception: "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'dodgeball5' (500 x 500)] position:{-140.00019836425781, -55.124687194824219} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{30, 30} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00"*. What am I doing incorrect?

```
class ClassicLevelScene: SKScene { 
// Right Pointing Cannons
var rightPointingCannon: [SKReferenceNode] = []

// Dodgeball 5 Constants
var dodgeball5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dodgeball5")

// Dodgeball SKActions
var dodgeballRepeat = SKAction()
let dodgeballMoveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -400, y: 0, duration: 0.5)
let dodgeballMoveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 400, y: 0, duration: 0.5)
let dodgeballMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let dodgeballWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
var dodgeballLeftSequence = SKAction()
var dodgeballRightSequence = SKAction()


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Cannon Setup
    for child in self.children {
      if child.name == "rightPointingCannon" {
        if let child = child as? SKReferenceNode {
            rightPointingCannon.append(child)
            dodgeball5.position = child.position
            run(SKAction.repeatForever(
              SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.run(spawnDodgeball),
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
                ])
            ))

        }
      }
    }
    
    // Dodgeball Right Sequence
    dodgeballRightSequence = SKAction.sequence([dodgeballMoveRight, dodgeballMoveDone, dodgeballWait])


}

func spawnDodgeball() {
    dodgeball5.zPosition = -1
    dodgeball5.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    addChild(dodgeball5)
    dodgeball5.run(dodgeballRightSequence)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming single ball and ball can go off screen:

I would actually recommend against cloning the sprite.
Simply reuse it.

Once it's off the screen, you can reset it's position and speed and display it again. No need to create lots of objects, if you only need one.

Comment: solid advice, but there are too many unknown variables to deduce if this would be relevant for this instance. We don't know how many balls could be on screen at a time. we don't even know if the ball can ever leave the screen

Comment: I agree with the first part. But even then a cache might be a better way of handling this. 
And since he removes the ball from screen, I think there is a limited time they are visible. Also, the name would imply that the number of balls in play is most likely limited.

But these are fair points.

Comment: agreed. I always try to push for caching and reuse. However I always base my answers on what I figure the skill set of the OP to be. I didn't feel that caching would help, but rather confuse based on code example and previous questions by OP. I tackled my answer by presenting a easy solution with easy to obtain results while offering small code suggestions for other aspects at the same time. I've seen many people fail on their first attempt and then get overwhelmed by complex solutions and then quit. Not saying yours is wrong because it is GREAT thinking, just justifying my baby steps answer

Answer (score 0):

One SKNode only can have 1 parent at time.

You need to create a new SKSpriteNode or clone the dodgeball5 before to add again on spawnDodgeball()

You can use

`addChild(dodgeball5.copy())`

instead of

`addChild(dodgeball5)`

But be make sure dodgeball5 have no parent before.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be unnecessarily complex.

all you need to do is copy() you ball and add it to your scene

Also all of your SKActions don't need to be declared at a class level

And it's not clear why you are creating an array of cannons when only one is instantiated

```
class ClassicLevelScene: SKScene { 

    // Dodgeball 5 Constants
    var dodgeball5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dodgeball5")
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    
        setupCannonAndBall()

        let dodgeballMoveRight = SKAction.moveBy(x: 400, y: 0, duration: 0.5)
        let dodgeballMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let dodgeballWait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)

        dodgeballRightSequence = SKAction.sequence([dodgeballMoveRight, dodgeballMoveDone, dodgeballWait])

        //setup sequences ^ before spawning ball
        let spawn = SKAction.run(spawnDodgeball)
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([spawn, wait])))
    }

    func setupCannonAndBall() {

        if let cannonRef = SKReferenceNode(fileNamed: "rightPointingCannon") {

            dodgeball5.position = cannonRef.position
            dodgeball5.isHidden = true
            dodgeball5.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
            dodgeball5.zPosition = -1
        }
    }

    func spawnDodgeball() {

        let dodgeball = dodgeball.copy()
        dodgeball.isHidden = false
        addChild(dodgeball)

        dodgeball.run(dodgeballRightSequence)
    }
}
```